# createComposeRule vs createEmptyComposeRule in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Could someone please explain the difference between createComposeRule() vs createEmptyComposeRule() in leymans terms? I am not sure what it is referring to when saying "Compose Host". Could someone provide an illustrative example of both cases?

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/junit4/package-summary#createEmptyComposeRule().

Answer (score 1):

The following explanation may not be extremely accurate, since op requested to explain the difference in a "simpler" manner and terms.

So the main difference as described in the documentation is the existence of a "Compose host" in the Rule created by `createComposeRule()` in contrast to `createEmptyComposeRule()`.

What is meant by "Compose host", it's actually an entry point for the Compose UI, to be set and rendered later onto the screen. Such an example is an actual android activity or a ComposeView, which provides a `setContent()` method to declare or "inject" your composable/es.

Now, most of the time you may want to only test your UI and related UI logic or behaviors, so you want an entry point to set your composable content and start testing. Thus you require a host for that. By calling `createComposeRule()` you are provided with a test rule which contains a host (an activity) to set you compose content:

```
composeRule.setContent { // your composable }
```

and so you don't have to worry about how to introduce your Compose UI to testing. There may also be a scenario where you can introduce your own activity which already sets a compose content, and in that case you can omit the `setContent()` call since your activity already does that. In this case you may use a test rule by calling:

```
createAndroidComposeRule<MyActivity>()
```

Now think of a scenario where you do not want a rule that automatically takes care of providing a "Compose host" and you may want to create a host by your self to address custom test cases. And that is the case where you use: `createEmptyComposeRule()`. (You may also notice that a rule provided by `createEmptyComposeRule()` does not have a `setContent()` method.)